# Create a ProgressBar without xml in Android

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to create a progressBar (not a **progressBar dialog**) using java only.

I can't make it work, all I get is:

[image]

*(an image that keep going round in circles)*

Here is my code:

```
    b4 = new Button(this);
    t4 = new ProgressBar(this);

    b4.setId(4);
    b4.setText(SensorData.sensorName[4]);
    b4.setTypeface(null, 1);
    b4.setTextSize(15);
    b4.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    b4.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    b4.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.icon, 0); // down

    // t4.setId(4);
    t4.setPadding(20, 10, 10, 10);
    t4.setIndeterminate(false);
    t4.setProgress(0);
    t4.setScrollBarStyle(ProgressBar.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);
    t4.setMax(100);
    t4.setVisibility(t4.VISIBLE);


    sensorsView.addView(b4, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sensorsView.addView(t4, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
```

What I want is an horizontal progressBar, do you know how can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
t4 = new ProgressBar(this);
```

to this:

```
t4 = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
t4.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL)
```

Comment: `t4` is a `ProgressBar`, not a `ProgressDialog`, and as such doesn't have a `setProgressStyle` method.